# How to check if a scala class is assignable from a java class

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, reflection

I want to be able to check if a certain Scala class is assignable from a certain Java class. As stated [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) it is not always possible to do D.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class).

Basically what I need is something like this:

```
def isAssignableFrom(scalaClass: Class[_], javaClass: Class[T]): boolean = {
    // magic
}
```

I have tested:

```
def m[T: ru.TypeTag, S: ru.TypeTag](x: T, y: S): Boolean = {
    val leftTag = ru.typeTag[T]
    val rightTag = ru.typeTag[S]
    leftTag.tpe <:< rightTag.tpe
}
```

as stated in the link from above. But it complains about the Java class not having a TypeTag:

```
error: No TypeTag available for Class[T]
```

I'm not that familiar with Scala yet so maybe there is a really simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
def isAssignableFrom(scalaClass: Class[_], javaClass: Class[T]): Boolean = {
    val javaClassType: ru.Type = getType(javaClass)
    val scalaClassType: ru.Type = getType(scalaClass)
    scalaClassType.<:<(javaClassType)
}

def getType[T](clazz: Class[T]): ru.Type = {
    val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader)
    runtimeMirror.classSymbol(clazz).toType
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a pair of types that work here? This gives false for scala.Int and java.lang.Integer